# Base de dados de CEP's

Tags: banco-de-dados, cep, https

Necessito de uma base de dados de CEP's para acesso em servidor https, se possível gratuita, você conhece alguma?

Comment: @bigown entenda a pergunta antes de marcar como duplicada

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Já usei o **ViaCEP**, é gratuito e funciona com HTTPS: http://viacep.com.br/.

Exemplo: http://viacep.com.br/ws/01001000/json/

```
{
  "cep": "01001-000",
  "logradouro": "Praça da Sé",
  "complemento": "lado ímpar",
  "bairro": "Sé",
  "localidade": "São Paulo",
  "uf": "SP",
  "unidade": "",
  "ibge": "3550308",
  "gia": "1004"
}
```

Sobre os tipos de retorno:

> Após o CEP, deve ser fornecido o tipo de retorno desejado, que deve
>   ser "json", "xml", "piped" ou "querty".

Comment: Acho que poderia editar a resposta para adicionar o `https://`, uma vez que o autor da pergunta diz "em servidor https" e o site suporta isto. ;)

Comment: Foi apenas um exemplo e está explícito na resposta que funciona com HTTPS.